# How to check string array specific cell string length?

Tags: java, arrays

i have a strings array.
i want to check the length of a string contained in X cell in that array,
in order to create another array with the length of that string.

i've tried using:

```
public static String[] originalToPrint = new String[10];
```

then getting strings from the user that will enter the strings array,
then:

```
int[] temp = new int[ originalToPrint[y].length() ];
```

but i get a NullPointerException

do you have any ideas?

thanks

Comment: How do you read the strings from the user?

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine, it seems you didn't write any string to the position `originalToPrint[y]`, so you get a  nullpointer when you accesss it and call `.length()` on `null`. You should post the method where you fill the array `originalToPrint` and where you get your index `y` from.

Comment: Asking the OP to show more code should be a comment, not an answer.